# add values in string array on runtime c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

i am getting string array  on runtime like this

```
    string[] array1 = {"5", "4", "2"};
```

values in array is added on runtime on the basis of checkbox selection from

screen (Note: i have 7 check boxes on screen )

if i check 3 check boxes then 3 values will be add in array1 but i want to add

zero at the end of the array  in   remaining 4 positions in array like this :

```
 string[] array1 = {"5", "4", "2","0" ,"0","0" , "0"};
```

during runtime just to fix all 7 position in array ...what should i do ??

Comment: Your question is confusing. You recieve an array with 3 values. Then if three checkboxes are checked you add 3 values? What three values? You have the exact same values you started with and you are simple adding zeros...

Comment: values will be added on the basis of some calculation i just want to add zero on the un checked check boxes position

Comment: Is position meaningul? If checkbox2 is unchecked, then 0 should be added at index 2 or you simply want to append 0s to the end of the array until the total amout is 7?

Comment: just append at the end of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get the usage of your requirement. But you can fill up the array with "0" with the following code:

```
List<string> list = array1.ToList();
for (int i = array1.Length; i < 7; i++)
{
    list.Add("0");
}
array1 = list.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
const int paddedSize = 7;
var newArray = array1.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("0", paddedSize - array1.Length)).ToArray();
```

But maybe you'll understand it better without using `Linq`; the type you want to use is `List<string>` which can be dynamically resized, arrays can't. In order to get a list out of an array, you can use the linq extension:

```
var resized = array1.ToList();
```

Or

```
var resized = new List<string>(array1);
```

And now you simply add `0s` until the total count of items is 7:

```
while (resized.Count < paddedSize)
    resized.Add("0");
```

And back to an array:

```
var newArray = resized.ToArray();
```

Comment: added zero with the help of list ...thanks for your time